# Description of $n\times{n}$ complex matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

How can I describe all the $n\times n$ complex matrices $A$ and $B$ such that $AB-BA=S_n$, where $S_n=(s_{ij})$ with $s_{ij}=0, i\not =j$ and $s_{ii}=i$?

I know that $AB-BA=I$ is impossible, because

if we suppose that $AB-BA=I$, we can see that $trace(AB-BA)=trace(I)$, which implies

$trace(AB)-trace(BA)=trace(I)$ which gives

$0=n$

A contradiction.

Comment: In $s_{ii}=i$ the LHS $i$ is the index or the imaginary unit?

Comment: it's index, Emilio.

Comment: But then it's again imposible: the trace of the result mut be zero.

Comment: Now I begin to see what the question is all about, but do you think the trace of $s_{ii}=i$ will be 0?@leonbloy

Answer (score 1):

There are no complex matrices the fullfill that condition.

$$AB-BA=S_n\implies tr(S_n)=0$$

But $tr(S_n)=1+2+\cdots + n >0$.